# Best strategy for splitting English-style names into first and last name

Tags: algorithm, split, pseudocode

I've got a list of names and I need to split them up into first and last names. Since some names have 2-3 spaces in them, a simple split for a space won't do.

What sort of heuristics do people use to perform the split?

Note that this isn't a duplicate of questions that effectively ask how to split at a space; I'm looking for heuristics and algorithms, not actual code help.

*Update*: I'm limiting the problem set to English-style names. This is all I need to solve and likely all that anyone approaching this (English language) question will need as well.

Comment: This is typically solved by keeping the first & last name data separate at all times, because it's pretty much impossible to get this right for all languages/countries/locales/etc. Not that that helps you any.

Comment: This depends a great deal on the language: can you try this with a dictionary of first names? I assume this is not in Chinese or Japanese, right?

Comment: Splitting names yourself is generally going to piss off someone.  How should Bobby de Luca, or Bobbie Lee Jensen, have their names split?  Or Chow Yun-Fat, for that matter?  (Chow is his *last* name.  Well...it's first, but last.  Oh, hell, you get the point.)

Comment: If you use the dictionary strategy, you should know that for some language, a first name can also be a last name. Like `Patrick Robert` and `Robert Patrick`

Comment: In some cases though, you *have* to provide separated names. LinkedIn's API for example requires you to split the name or they won't let you do an out-of-network search.

Comment: @MattBall In my case its a search box, where having two boxes kind of smells bad. In general though I agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've read a very interesting and comprehensive post on this subject:

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

It even suggests to ask yourself whether you really need separate fields for first and last names. It seems to depend on the target region(s) of your application.

Comment: You might also find http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches can help, though not fully solve this problem.

1. Programatically separate the easy ones, the ones that are not easy get pushed into a different list, "remaining to be split".  Manually sort that list.  As you manually sort, some heuristics might emerge which could be coded, further reducing the size of the remaining list.  If this is a one-time thing, and list is not super massive, this will get the job done.
2. A closely related problem is when a name is split, but you don't know which is the first and which is last.  Some systems work around this problem by doing fuzzy lookups such that if on the first attempt no match is found, flip the first and last name and try again.  You didn't say *why* you need to split the names.  If it is to lookup against reference data, consider some kind of similar fuzzy lookup heuristics which allow for trying different splits instead of trying to get the split correct up-front.

Not really an answer, but in this case there really is no perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Different countries and regions have different formats for names. For example, Asia the family name is usually first and then given names follows. The West, you’ve got the first name and last name convention, but gets complicated when people double barrel, or include middle names. And then some regions people are only given one name.

Personally, I don’t think there’s one single algorithm that can give you 100% accurate results I’m afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes English-style surnames.  If that's not the case, please update your question.

It's usually safe to assume that the last space character signals the start of a person's surname.  But since there are exceptions, one strategy would be to compile a large database of known multi-word surnames from some other source.  You could then test for these surnames, and treat them as exceptions.